# How can I write a trigger in mysql that after an insert to the table deletes the row?

Tags: mysql, triggers, delete-row

I've got an **after insert** trigger that works well.

However, I want it to delete the row after it's been inserted and after the main body of the trigger completes.

How can I do that?

I have a unique id in the table.

Comment: you want to delete the row after inserting? so why do you insert it then in the first place? *puzzledlook*

Comment: remote server insert it to this table he have a access only to insert,
i check the row and in some case (i use if statement ) i decide to insert it to my tables , and delete the row

Comment: Then how about a delete statement in the if?

Comment: Have you considered using a stored procedure instead of an insert?

Comment: i try this to CALL A PROCEDURE USING TRIGGERS
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,125666,125672

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. You can't modify the target table with an AFTER trigger.

Comment: A feature that is missing from MySQL, for certain. MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL all support this. 

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,249709#msg-249709